# Stereomix and flash

Tags: 12.04, sound, flash, microphone

I have a problem with using stereomix and flash. I'm not able to access to flash settings, like I done on windows. I installed an pavucontrol, and I have stereomix on audacity, but not on the flashplayer.

How to stream in the real time from microphone and internal sound?